# Best Practices Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, version-control, drupal-7

What are the best practices to do changes(new modules, new requirements, new content type, modifications) on the existing site which is live & is being used by users?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, before doing any change on live site would be good to create backup of files and database. Backup & migrate module may be helpful for that:
https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Then it's not advised to work directly on live site. Download it and set up site locally, on some virtual machine or make staging site or similar, to work on.

Third, would be good to stick with the standards already used on existing site so you won't have situation that each new developer that works on site has it's one rules.